# Frequency Shift Keying

Tags: fsk

The following signal is an example of frequency shift keying. Let the
pulse rate be 100 bits/sec. If f1 = 1324 hz what should f2 be for the two tones
to be orthogonal?

[image]

I know that the formula to solve this is delta F = 1/2T, and I am given f1....what I am not understanding is what is T? Is it 1/pulse rate, which is 100 bits/sec?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, no my question is I know that the formula to solve this is delta F = 1/2T, and I am given f1....what I am not understanding is what is T? Is it 1/pulse rate, which is given as 100 bits/sec?

Comment: $T$ is the duration of one symbol, for example the pattern 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 is 8 symbols.